# union from 2 select with join

Tags: mysql, join, union

Please guys I need help about a syntax for select.

I need make union of two select result from join.

I try to explain

```
SELECT FROM 2 TABLE BY JOIN 
UNION
SELECT FROM 2 OTHER TABLE BY UNION
```

OR

I tried:

```
select .... join.... data from table2for union
union
select .... join ... data from table1 for union
```

the table I will union is the result from the join of 2 table.

Other data for understand:

```
tabA1
codice
nome
totale
JOIN
tabA2
restocodice
restonome

UNION

tabB1
codiceconf
nomeconf
totaleconf
JOIN
tabB2
restocodiceconf
restonomeconf
```

I hope I explained.

Comment: Please, can you write the JOIN correctly? So we can work on UNION question.

Comment: Dear, I advice you to learn basically SQL by book. I think you're italian reading field name, so I send you this link: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/it/sql.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from taba1 
left join taba2 
on taba1.col=taba2.col

union

select * 
from tabb1 
left join tabb2
 on tabb1.col=tabb2.col
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the general structure:

```
SELECT cols
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON join-conditions
WHERE more-conditions

UNION

SELECT cols
FROM table3
JOIN table4 ON join-conditions
WHERE more-conditions
```

Comment: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns AND THIS IS TRUE, how i can resolv this ?? thank you for help

Comment: When you make a union, all the subqueries have to return the same number of columns. If there's nothing from the table to put in some of the columns, use a value like `0`, `NULL`, or `""` in the other